# Conditional expectation of legitimate emails

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

While Fred is sleeping one night, $X$ legitimate emails and $Y$ spam emails are sent tohim. Suppose that X and Y are independent, with $X$ ~$ Pois(10)$ and $Y $ ~ $Pois(40)$.When he wakes up, he observes that he has $30$ new emails in his inbox. Given this information, what is the expected value of how many new legitimate emails he has?

Comment: this seems a question of some homework or assignment. you should show what you have tried and that you have made an effort to solve the question.

Comment: Well , X+Y follows pois(50)...so we have to find E(X|X+Y=30). I tried to evaluate the sum and somehow i got an absurd answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(X,Y)$ be the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ and $p(X)=\text{Pois}(X|\lambda=10)$ and $p(Y)=\text{Pois}(Y|\lambda=40)$ the marginals for $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Due to independence, $p(X,Y)=p(X)p(Y)$.

As you said, the random variable $X+Y$ follows a distribution $p(X+Y)=\text{Pois}(X+Y|\lambda=50)$.

We also need the conditional distribution $p(X|X+Y=30)$, which, by definition, is given by:

$p(X|X+Y=30) = \frac{p(X,X+Y=30)}{p(X+Y=30)}=\frac{p(X,Y=30-X)}{p(X+Y=30)}=\frac{p(X)p(Y=30-X)}{p(X+Y=30)}$.

The denominator ${p(X+Y=30)}$ is constant, let's call it $k$. The numerator is some function of $X$ which you can easily compute by taking the product of the two Poisson distributions $p(X)$ and $p(Y=30-X)$. Let's call it $f(X)$. Then, $p(X|X+Y=30) = \frac{1}{k}f(X)$.

Finally, your result is given by:

$\mathbb{E}_{p(X|X+Y)}[X]=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{x=0}^{30}xf(x)$.

Now, it's just a matter of computing $k$, $f(X)$ and the sum above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually i thought $p(X=x,Y=30-x)$=$p(Y=30-x) $ and things got messed up! ☺

Comment: That's ok ;) when you have a question, it is useful to show what you have tried and add the steps that you have followed (even if there's some mistake on them). This shows that you have actually made an effort to solve the question and helps people who are willing to help you. :)

Comment: Okay...i will keep that in mind from now on.